# Importing .csv or excel testcases in SOAP UI

Tags: web-services, soapui, load-testing

I am using SOAP UI to test our RESTful search service. The search request is of the form :

```
 {               "className": "Pets",
                "searchType": "SearchResult",
                "query": "German shephard",
                "filterQuery": {"subClassName" = "Dogs"},
                "sortType": null,
                "startPageFrom": 0,
                "distance": 100.0,
                "latitude": 34.069784,
                "longitude": -118.34901,
                "pageSize": 20,
                "randomSeed": 0,
                "notBackfillable": false,
}
```

I want to test about 200 search terms (obtained from logs) along with multiple combinations of the other request parameters. The number of test cases can hence easily exceed thousand. Instead of creating each test case in SOAP UI i would like to create an .csv or excel sheet to import these testcases in to SOAP UI (Which i can later run as load tests). Does anybody know of a way to do this? I have been through SOAP UI's documentation but haven't found anything useful. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the pro version you can achieve this very easily using a File Datasource and a DataSourceLoop test steps like mentioned [here](http://www.soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/data-driven-tutorial/Implementation.html). If you are using the basic version, you will need to write a groovy script for this. [This blog article](http://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/groovy-datasource-teststep-dataloop-teststep-using-groovy-in-soapui/) presents a similar groovy script.

Comment: Thanks! I am using the basic version, but i dont have time to invest in learning groovy. I guess i will start with a baseline manual test and then ramp up on learning groovy.