# How do I place Multi-Hierarchical data in Functional Testing in SoapUI

Tags: xml, excel, soap, csv, soapui

I want to do some testing and want to know if SoapUI can handle generating requests where elements can have more than set of values. For example, if I wanted to send an XML with the body:

```
<bookList>
  <book>
    <title>Little Red Riding Hood</title>
    <author>B. B. Wolf</author>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>Humpty Dumpty</title>
    <author>M. Goose</author>
  </book>
</bookList>
```

Sometimes I will want two books, others three, sometimes even none. Is there a way to generate functional testing using Excel or CSV for situations where there element lists (that can vary in total number of elements)? Either through Groovy or SoapUI pro? I can't seem to find anything on SoapUI's site about this type of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4436) example it will help you
also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890050/importing-csv-or-excel-testcases-in-soap-ui)

Comment: Neither examples are valid. They indicate situations where there's one value for each element, in a tabular fashion. I want to know if SoapUI can handle list situations, where the size of the list of elements can change from each request.